# Error compiling cumulocity-clients-java with java 11

Tags: java, java-11, cumulocity

I would like to develop using cumulocity api, so I downloaded the sources for java examples (https://bitbucket.org/m2m/cumulocity-clients-java) version 1004.7.0.

When trying to compile it with java 11 (openjdk 11.0.2) using maven I have the following exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project device-capability-model: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeTags -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project device-capability-model: Fatal error compiling
....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeTags
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass (ClassLoader.java:718)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:588)
    at lombok.launch.ShadowClassLoader.loadClass (ShadowClassLoader.java:422)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:315)
    at lombok.javac.JavacTreeMaker$SchroedingerType.getFieldCached (JavacTreeMaker.java:156)
    at lombok.javac.JavacTreeMaker$TypeTag.typeTag (JavacTreeMaker.java:245)
    at lombok.javac.Javac.<clinit> (Javac.java:155)
    at lombok.javac.handlers.HandleGetter.<clinit> (HandleGetter.java:303)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:398)
    at lombok.core.SpiLoadUtil$1$1.next (SpiLoadUtil.java:111)
    at lombok.javac.HandlerLibrary.loadAnnotationHandlers (HandlerLibrary.java:171)
    at lombok.javac.HandlerLibrary.load (HandlerLibrary.java:156)
    at lombok.javac.JavacTransformer.<init> (JavacTransformer.java:44)
    at lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor.init (LombokProcessor.java:89)
    at lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor$JavacDescriptor.want (AnnotationProcessor.java:87)
    at lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor.init (AnnotationProcessor.java:140)
    at lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor.init (AnnotationProcessor.java:69)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ProcessorState.<init> (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:678)
```

For reference, the maven command used was:

> mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -e

Is there a version that compiles with java 11? Or what configurations do I need to make to compile this with java 11?

Comment: can you post pom.xml here ?

Comment: You need to update the Lombok dependency to 1.18.4 or later

Comment: I have 1.18.10 and still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

In the maven pom.xml file comment the following two line.s

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
```

You will have to replace the following piece of code

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
```

with the following code in pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>11</release>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

You can check.

Comment: I have tried your solution, but now I have:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project device-capability-model: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /E:/data/git_repos/cumulocity/m2m-cumulocity-clients-java-3d14ee967178/device-capability-model/src/main/java/c8y/RemoteAccessCredentialsType.java:[16,46] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getPassword()
[ERROR]   location: variable credentials of type c8y.RemoteAccessCredentials`

These appear on device-capability-model.

Comment: The error clearly says about the problem of credentials, it means either you are not passing the password or you are using a wrong password.

Comment: I think somewhere you are using username and password to download the artifacts. As per your question, the problem regarding compilation is solved. If you post a new question regarding this, people will be able to help you.

Comment: Credentials are not required when downloading Cumulocity artifacts with Maven. Just use the repositories provided in https://cumulocity.com/guides/microservice-sdk/java/